# Bitbucket IP whitelisting in EC2 security group

Tags: amazon-ec2, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I want to whitelist Bitbucket IP by adding it to the security group of EC2 instance.

I have followed the steps on link :
https://bitbucket.org/blog/new-ip-addresses-bitbucket-cloud

I have added following IPs:

**IPv4: 18.205.93.0/25, 18.234.32.128/25, and 13.52.5.0/25**

But still Bitbucket pipelines are not able to connect to EC2 instance.

Can anyone please help me with it ?

Comment: Can you share the error if any?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want Bitbucket Pipelines to connect to your EC2 instance, then you need to see the Pipelines section of https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/what-are-the-bitbucket-cloud-ip-addresses-i-should-use-to-configure-my-corporate-firewall-343343385.html (as included on the link you posted). The IPs you've listed are for your EC2 instance to connect to Bitbucket, not for Bitbucket to connect to your EC2 instance.

Comment: Not sure if these are still working. I added all of them but EC2 is still blocking access with NET_ERR response

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is not correct. You need the *outgoing* IPs, which can be found on [IP addresses and domains for Atlassian cloud products](https://support.atlassian.com/organization-administration/docs/ip-addresses-and-domains-for-atlassian-cloud-products/) (section "Outgoing Connections").

Comment: This is incorrect, the list you mentioned is for web services like webhooks (although they don't make that clear).  They do not work for pipelines.  I just tested it.  The accepted answer is correct.